# Fazer insert com chave estrangeira

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um insert com chave estrangeira porém nao estou conseguindo, dando o seguinte erro

```
GRAVE: null
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "agendamento" violates foreign key constraint "fk_cliente"
  Detalhe: Key (id_cliente)=(0) is not present in table "cliente".
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2310)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2023)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:166)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
    at Model.DAO.AgendamentoDAO.insert(AgendamentoDAO.java:45)
    at Controller.AgendaController.agendar(AgendaController.java:79)
    at View.Agenda.ButtonAgendarActionPerformed(Agenda.java:180)
    at View.Agenda.access$300(Agenda.java:22)
    at View.Agenda$4.actionPerformed(Agenda.java:148)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Segue o meu método de insert:

```
 public void insert(Agendamento agendamento) throws SQLException{

    String sql = "insert into agendamento(id_cliente,id_servico,valor,data,observacao)values('" + agendamento.getCliente().getId() + "','" + agendamento.getServico().getId() + "','" + agendamento.getValor() + "','" + agendamento.getData() + "','" + agendamento.getObservacao() + "')";

    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.execute();
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nas duas primeiras linhas já diz qual o problema:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "agendamento" violates foreign key constraint "fk_cliente" Detalhe: Key (id_cliente)=(0) is not present in table "cliente". at
```

Ou seja você esta tentando incluir na tabela agendamento um id de cliente qua não existe na tabela cliente, deste modo você esta parando na restrição referencial. Outra coisa que pode ser também, já me aconteceu de esquecer de configurar o id como a chave primaria e na hora de inserir em uma tabela que usava como chave estrangeira dava um erro parecido com esse seu

Answer (score -1):

Muito genérico o que pode está causando isso, alem de poucas informações do seu código. Faz um debug e vê onde esta estourando.
veja se não está enviando algum valor null no post aonde não deveria.